# How to compute distribution conditional on two random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

I hope that this question is appropriate for this site; I have tried Math.SE, but haven't had much luck so far. I am dealing with the following scenario:

A fair coin is tossed, and we record the result "heads" or "tails" as random variable $Z$. If a head is observed, a random sample $X_1,\dots,X_n \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ is collected, with fixed sample size $n$. If a tail is observed, a random sample $X_1,X_2,\dots \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ is collected until $k$ successes are obtained, for some $k<n$. Let $N$ denote the random variable recording the total number of $X$s observed, and let $M$ denote the number of successes in the observed $Xs$.

> I must show that the distribution of $Z$, given $N$ and $M$, does not depend on $\theta$.

Say $Z=0$ represents "heads" and $Z=1$ represents "tails". We can then find conditional distributions for random variables $N$ and $M$. Here is what I have found so far.

$\text{P}[N=j|Z=0]=\begin{cases}0 \text{ if } j\neq n \\ 1 \text{ if } j=n\end{cases} \\ \text{P}[N=j|Z=1]=\binom{j-1}{k-1}\theta^k(1-\theta)^{j-k},j=k,k+1,\dots$

$\text{P}[M=j|Z=0]=\binom{n}{j}\theta^j(1-\theta)^{n-j}, j=0,1,\dots,n\\ \text{P}[M=j|Z=1]=\begin{cases}0 \text{ if } j\neq k \\ 1 \text{ if } j=k\end{cases}$

I have taken the first few steps, using the definition of conditioning and the law of total probability. 
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{P}[Z=z|N=j,M=j]&=&\frac{\text{P}[N=j,M=j|Z=z]\text{P}[Z=z]}{\text{P}[N=j,M=j]} \\
&=&\frac{\text{P}[N=j,M=j|Z=z]\text{P}[Z=z]}{\sum_z\text{P}[N=j,M=j|Z=z]\text{P}[Z=z]}
\end{eqnarray}

Here is where I am stuck. I cannot figure out how to use the above information to finish this computation. In particular, one of the distributions above involves $k$, and the other one does not--will I ever be able to get rid of the dependency on $\theta$ then? Also, I am not certain how to find the joint distribution of $M$ and $N$. I would greatly appreciate any hints on how to proceed--I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Why are you assuming that both $N$ and $M$ have the same value $j$?

Comment: I just used that to represent the value each random variable takes on, but I am not completely sure that I set up the problem correctly. Is there a better way for me to think about this problem?

Comment: If I have understood the problem correctly, there is only one possible value of $(N,M)$ that does not determine $Z$ uniquely: it is when $(N,M)=(n,k)$. Thus there is only one (simple) calculation you need to make.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, I don't quite understand. Would I do this calculation by continuing to use the conditioning argument I started above?

Comment: Maybe it would become clearer if you were to draw a probability tree.